# Positively graded k-algebra

Tags: abstract-algebra, representation-theory

Suppose we have a positively graded $k$-algebra $A=\bigoplus_{i\ge 0}A_i$, such that $A_0$ has finite global dimension. Furthermore, all $A_i$ are finite dimensional and $A$ is generated in degree $0$ and $1$, i.e. $A_1A_i=A_{i+1}$.

1) Is $A$ a semi-perfect ring?

2) Can 1) be reduced to the question if $A_0$ is semi-perfect?

Comment: Isn't $k[x]$, with $x$ in degree one, a counterexample?

Comment: Ah I see. This means that in general there is no projective cover for finitely generated $A$-modules, right. But is there something like minimal projective resolution for finitely generated $A$-modules $M$ as in the case where $A_0$ is semisimple (for instance when studying Koszul algebras)?

Comment: Ah! Are you only concerned with graded modules and maps? I think you will have "graded semi-perfectness" (i.e., there will be projective covers in the category of graded modules, but not in the ungraded module category).

Comment: Exactely. I am interested in graded projective covers. Do they exist for finitely generated graded $A$-modules ($A$ as above )? I would be greatful for some literature on this topic.

Comment: I've not read it in detail, but the first couple of sections of "Graded, Selfinjective, and Koszul Algebras" by R. Martinez-Villa (J.Algebra 215, 34-72 (1999)), and some of the references he gives there, look as though might be useful for you.